# How to partially merge branches in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I have two branches in mercurial A and B, both of them have `tests.py` file but I don't want to merge those files when I merge A and B. How to ignore only `tests.py` and auto merge everything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to simply "ignore" the changes to a file when merging.  What you can do is pick which version of `tests.py` (either the version from branch A or B) you want to go into the merge changeset and use that.

Since `hg merge` leaves the changes caused by merging two branches in your working copy, to give you a chance to fix up conflicts, etc, you can revert `tests.py` in the working copy before you commit to whichever version you'd like to keep.  Here's an example:

```
$ hg update A   # switch to branch A
$ hg merge B    # merge w/ branch B
...
$ hg status
M tests.py
M some_other_file
...
# reset tests.py to version from either branch A or B.  
# Let's pick A since that was our original parent.
$ hg revert -r A tests.py
$ hg commit
```

Note that `hg merge B` might produce conflicts in `tests.py`, so if you use `hg revert -r A tests.py` you'd also need to mark the conflict as being resolved with `hg resolve -m tests.py`.